# Best Practices for re-raising the same error in Python

Tags: python, exception

I have a few functions in a call stack that will re-raise the same exception up the stack in the case of an error. I am familiar with the Python idiom that a standalone `raise` in a `try/except` block will re-raise the same exception being handled, but an exception will still be raised if a call is not in a `try/except` block.

Assuming that the exceptions are handled higher up in the call stack, would `inbounds1()` or `inbounds2()` be considered "better" practice, or neither?

```py
import numpy as np


class ArrayShapeError(Exception):
    ...


def get_distance(points):
    if points.ndim != 2 or points.shape[1] != 3:
        raise ArrayShapeError("Parameter 'points' is not of shape (n, 3)")

    return np.linalg.norm(points, axis=1)


# Implicit try/except
def inbounds1(points):
    return get_distance(points) < 1


# Explicitly try/except and re-raise
def inbounds2(points):
    try:
        return get_distance(points) < 1
    except ArrayShapeError:
        raise


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ok
    print(inbounds1(np.random.rand(5, 3)))
    print(inbounds2(np.random.rand(5, 3)))

    # Raises ArrayShapeError
    print(inbounds1(np.random.rand(5, 2)))
    print(inbounds2(np.random.rand(5, 2)))
```

Comment: In `inbounds2`, what are you trying to accomplish by catching an exception you don't intend to handle?

Comment: Where do you ultimately want to handle the exception? The question seems borderline opinion based.

Comment: @paisanco I should have clarified that exceptions are handled higher up in the call stack. Fixing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use inbounds2().

This is because re-raising the error is a good practice not only for insurance but also for readability for you and other people reading your code - it makes it clearer.

There's not a huge technical advantage as the error has already been raised.

Comment: Good old PEP 20 strikes again... "Explicit is better than implicit." Ironic that the approach I took in my codebase was to go the implicit route for "cleanliness". Time for a refactor!